# import json to csv in python

Tags: python, json, csv

When I use the following code, I keep getting an error even though it creates the csv file. I need help and am fairly new to python.

The error i receive is "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/parse-json.py", line 34, in 
    values = [ x.encode('utf8') for x in item['fields'].values() ]
TypeError: string indices must be integers"

```
import json
from pprint import pprint

with open('data.json') as data_file:    
data = json.load(data_file)

#pprint(data)

# calc number of alert records in json file
x = len(data['alerts'])


count = 0
while (count < x):
    #print 'COUNT = ', count
    print data['alerts'][count]['message']
    print data['alerts'][count]['tags']
    print data['alerts'][count]['teams']
    print data['alerts'][count]['id']
    count = count + 1

import json
import csv

f = open('data.json') 
data = json.load(f)
f.close()

f = csv.writer(open('yes.csv', 'wb+'))

for item in data:
    values = [ x.encode('utf8') for x in item['fields'].values() ]
    f.writerow([item['pk'], item['model']] + values)
```

Comment: Are those two separate files? You have the same import twice.

Comment: Also, we won't be able to diagnose your problem because we don't have your data. Create an [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), preferably that uses part of data.json directly as a string instead of leaving it in a file. (Doing so might even make the problem obvious to you.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to check your data structures.
Basically what the error is saying is that `item` is not a dictionary.

From what I see in your code, you are iterating over `data`, but data is not a list of dictionaries but a dictionary itself.

If you want to iterate through the elements in a dict, you should do one the following:

```
for key, value in data.items():
```

or if you only want to iterate through the values:

```
for value in data.values():
```